# Filipina under working visa in Oman wishes to travel to India

Tags: visas, india, filipino-citizens

I am a Filipina under working visa in Oman. Can I travel to India and if yes does Filipino citizens have visa on arrival to India and if no what is the requirement?

Answer (score 3):

The Philippines is listed as one of the countries who passport holders are eligible for an e-visa.

Assuming you intent to travel to India for tourism purposes, you you apply on the official website:

> https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/evisa/tvoa.html

Please note, this isn't a visa on arrival, you have to submit your details online before departure.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply for an eVisa providing you meet the eligibility criteria https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/evisa/tvoa.html